# Rechargeable battery, power multiplexor and charging battery

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, power-electronics

I have a Raspberry Pi and a bunch of peripherials (web cam, WiFi dongle, H-bridge + DC motor, servo). Alltogether they consume ~4.5A when everything is  active. And I would like to make this device mobile.

For this I've chose an AGM 6V 12Ah rechargeable battery. It works fine until charge ends :( I take it out from device and set for charge.

I would like to build own power circuitry that will:

- switch between power sources: when DC adapter appears it stops using the battery and uses DC source
- when DC is present charge the battery as needed (overcharge protection)
- when battery charge is lower than 5.4V shutdown (discharge protection)

Is there any existing solution I can apply or some existing solution I can adapt to my needs?

P. S. It would be awesome if you would also suggest some in-depth reading on power circuitry design. I've tried to google, but there are thousands of options and I don't know which one to chose :(

Comment: Asking for existing solution - question isn't about electronic design and should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Or'ing controllers (http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-or-controllers-ideal-diodes/2556704), they will help with the switching logic (battery vs external DC when charging), the LTC4415 http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4415fa.pdf has a 6A internal forward current limit which seems like its suitable for your application. They also have example circuits for battery charging applications in the datasheets.

Edit: Didnt notice the battery was 6V, the LTC4415 wont be suitable but you there should be an IC that accomodates for your voltage range